# Solve $x \arccos(x)+x/2=\cos(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

$$x \arccos(x)+x/2=\cos(2x)$$

I dont know how to solve this one. It looks relatively easy but it is not, not for me at least.

Anybody to help?

Comment: Hint, plot each side of the equation and see if there is a point of intersection. This will reveal a lot and hopefully provide you with a next step/approach to solving it.

Comment: I don't think there are ways of solving this other than graphically.